# Did any ancient polytheistic religion hold that theirs was the only pantheon?

Tags: religion

There are a handful of polytheistic pantheons that we are generally familiar with today, The Greek pantheon, the pre-Christianity Roman pantheon, and the Norse gods; while I see this from a western Christian lens, I also am vaguely aware that Indian religions and at the very least far east religions may be polytheistic.

The major mono-theistic religions I'm familiar with today assert that theirs is the only god which of course excludes the possibility that other cultures could be correct, however in polytheistic religions there is no assertion that there is one god.

In the ancient world there was certainly some trade across long distances where existing cultures would encounter other polytheistic religions (I'm thinking Greek/Roman trade with say Egypt for example which had two different pantheons) -- are there records of how differing pantheons were handled? Were the pantheons largely merged, or alternatively, were there any claims of "No, there are only [defined set of gods], yours is not a god" recorded in history?

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  The examples of the Greeks and Romans ()particularly with respect to the Egyptian pantheon, which was incorporated into the Roman, and the Jewish and Christian religions, which were suppressed) and of the Chinese and Japanese would seem to be particularly instructive.

Comment: The scope of this question should be narrowed.  Presently, it's asking about thousands of years of history and countless belief systems.  You might find it interesting to look at Greek borrowings from Levantine cultures - perhaps contrasting how certain gods are merged (e.g. Herakles and Melqart) and others are borrowed outright (e.g. Adonis)

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion of the complex interactions between Buddhism and Hinduism in Southeast Asia: https://www.iseas.edu.sg/images/pdf/nsc_working_paper_series_1.pdf

Comment: Few if any ancient religions had a theology or a canon of beliefs, and a religion, while sometimes being similar over a wide region varied a lot in detail from village to village. The Norse religion seems clear enough today, but this is because most of what we know about it comes from a synthesis by a 13th century Icelandic antiquarian.  We *know* that Norse beliefs varied profoundly in both space and time. The Romans didn't *care* what people believed or even if they believed at all, as long as they carried out the right rituals.  I think your question may looking with too modern an eye.

Comment: My answer to a related question may help you. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/45414/did-roman-empire-elite-believe-in-their-gods/45434#45434

Comment: I highly recommend this series of articles about how polytheism (particularly in the ancient world) worked in practice, which will answer your question and give you a much clearer lens through which to understand such cultures: https://acoup.blog/2019/10/25/collections-practical-polytheism-part-i-knowledge/

Comment: *The major mono-theistic religions I'm familiar with today assert that theirs is the only god which of course excludes the possibility that other cultures could be correct* — or that their gods are one and the same (Judaism, Christianity, Islam)

Comment: @dbmag9 Excellent articles -- very enlightening!

Comment: Early Christians were accused of atheism - because they didn't recognize the other gods.

Comment: A sort of tangential point here: my understanding is that it's well established that early Judaism didn't claim that there was only one god that was real, it was just that their god was 'jealous' and did not tolerate the worship of other gods.  Some still did as evidenced in the archeological record and reflected in the Moses story.

Comment: I need to write a meta answer on false aggregations.  "Polytheistic religions" is a false category, and ill serves to predict their behavior. As noted above, the Romans sometimes incorporated, sometimes tolerated and sometimes ?syncreted? other religions, while on the other hand sometimes persecuted. Studying these as a group is going to mislead the historical narrative.

Comment: I've altered this to ask if *any* ancient polytheistic religion held that other pantheons were nonexistent. We know that at least some didn't. It's well known that the ancient Roman religion  incorporated gods from conquered countries. From the little I've read on the subject, ritual was more important than belief. That is, performing the sacrifice was more important that doing it with true belief in one's heart.

Comment: While I'm sympathetic to the question - it is interesting - I cannot support re-open without (1) prior research, and (2) a narrower focus  Ne Mo's edit helps significantly, but I'm still concerned about false aggregation and false equivalencies.  Could OP take a step back and try to clarify what OP really wants to know?  How do the cited examples not answer the question?  If we can get a clear question, it could be a very valuable answer.

Answer (score 44):

The polytheists did not regard "pantheons" as schematically as we see them in mythology books.

There were some general approaches in polytheist religions when you encountered people with different gods and practices:

- Ignore it all.  You continue to practice the rites of your ancestors, your neighbor continues to practice the rites of *his* ancestors, all is well.
- Identify your neighbor's god as one of yours.  This happened so thoroughly with the Greeks and Romans that we now regard them as one god with two names, despite discrepancies, but it was more widespread.  For instance, Hermes was identified not only with Mercury but with the Egyptian Thoth and the Germanic Woden.  Gods in inscriptions often have long lists of names.
- Adopt the worship of a particular god.  Apollo was adopted by the Romans, perhaps because they had no god to identify him with.

It is hard to tell any pattern, particularly with the evidence as sparse as it is.

*Paganism in the Roman Empire* by Ramsay MacMullen is good on this.

Comment: the second option also clearly happened within the Greek religion itself. The many local epithets of many gods within Greece are used to describe the god in a huge variety of roles that are sometimes mutually contradictory

Comment: The Greek and Roman gods are still considered distinct in that the different cultures had different traditions regarding them, even though they both believed they were the same gods. As for modern times, I know that _Jeopardy!_ will consider your response incorrect if you give a Greek god's name when they want a Roman god's name or vice versa (e.g., a statue of Hermes is not considered a statue of Mercury).

Comment: The Greek pantheon may contain an earlier pantheon which it absorbed (the Titans). Likewise with less evidence, the Norse pantheon (Ice giants?)

Comment: I don't know much about it, but the Hindu religion is polytheistic, and also a major religion in today's world.

Comment: There are records of Indian religions (Buddhism, Hinduism) influencing Ancient Greek and Roman religions and vice-versa; because of substantial trade between these civilizations. See for example [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece%E2%80%93Ancient_India_relations#Mythology_and_legends) section on influence on Greek religion.

Comment: @KefSchecter. Yes, there were always discrepancies.   Mars was a lot more favorably viewed, and a god of agriculture as well as war

Comment: @Dhara. Shinto declared Buddhist priests the proper people to perform funerals.   Greece and Rome and the rest are convenient examples of a lot of collisions.

Answer (score 16):

> however in polytheistic religions there is no assertion that there is one god.

True. That's one of the major differences between mono- and polytheistic religions.

I live in Thailand. Once I visited [Wat Hua Lamphong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wat_Hua_Lamphong), close to the *(former)* railway station. To my surprise, I saw statues of Jesus, Joseph and Mary. The temple also has many statues of Hindu deities as well as statues of kings Rama V and IX. They are treated with exactly the same deference. People pray in front of them, light incense, make donations.

My home is very close to the [Erawan shrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erawan_Shrine). This is a shrine dedicated to the Hindu god Brahma. Not to Buddha, as you might expect, but to a specific Hindu god.

I've been in many smaller local temples, you often see statues of Chinese or Hindu deities. Polytheistic religions have no problems with that. But by default, that is impossible in any monotheistic religion. Even the concept is difficult to comprehend *(hence the question)*.

That is current, today. Not something people did in the past.

I understand - coming from a monotheistic religion - some people find it weird or difficult to understand. In a monotheistic religion, there is only one god. Therefore, all other gods are not real gods.

Polytheistic religions do not have this problem. Any god is a god. They have no problem 'integrating the competition' in a temple. For monotheists, Brahma and Buddha are not real gods. For Hindus and Buddhists, Christian deities are just as much gods as their own deities.

The same applies to the present and to the past.

Comment: Some evangelicals regard the different names of a single God as different faces of the one, true, God.  Other, more fundamentalist believers regard this as false.  Notably there is much discussion over YHVH/Allah.

Comment: @TheHonRose  Very true, and lets not get started on parton saints :)

Comment: "parton saints?" While I admire [Dolly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_Parton), she's not even Catholic!! (No offense, i just needed a laugh this morning and thought I'd share. if I had a nickel for every time I've typed the wrong spelling.....)

Comment: Maria+Saints vs just the Trinity: we had a few centuries of killing each other over that argument amongst others in Europe!  It even, in part, led to the creation of the United States.  Dangerous waters to paddle in.

Comment: I've deleted some comments that were flagged for crossing over from the context of history to the context of theological discussion, and therefore are going to invite defense of doctrine rather than informing historical narrative.

Comment: ‘Not to Buddha, as you might expect, but to a specific Hindu god.’ Why would anyone expect a Hindu shrine to be dedicated to Buddha? They’re not even all that closely related other than place of origin.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn at guess because ~94% of Thailand's Buddhist, with the remainder almost entirely Muslim or Christian; so the surprising thing would be that it was a Hindu shrine in the first place.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn In a strictly [Theravada] Buddhist country, one would expect that.

Comment: @MCW and made some subsequent comments incomprehensible! My comment was **not** theological, merely suggesting Christianity, intentionally or not, shared some elements with the prevailing polytheism.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Buddhism in Thailand heavily integrates Hindu elements. Most of SE Asia was historically Hindu, but later adopted Buddhism. Angkor Wat for example was originally constructed as a Hindu temple, but became Buddhist in the 12th c. There are representations of Hindu deities in many Buddhist contexts throughout Thailand, Wat Arun in Bangkok for example is named for the Hindu god Aruna. That doesn't make it Hindu, it's a Buddhist wat. The regnal name of the current ruling dynasty, who are constitutionally Buddhist, is Rama, one of the avatars of Vishnu.

Answer (score 8):

Polytheistic pantheons do not appear fully formed out of nowhere, like Athena out of Zeus's head.

Every settlement had its own local deity, and neighbors had to trade, so they had to avoid religious strife, so they had to reconcile their local deities. The easiest way to do that is to agree that your god is (say) a brother of mine.
And thus a pantheon is built up.

Followers of a polytheistic pantheon would be willing to accommodate another deity into their "godly family" as long as it carries a political/economic benefit (alliance or trade).

However, meeting an alternative *pantheon* (as opposed to an individual god) would imply meeting a completely different culture (like Greeks vs Persians) and reconciling pantheons could be too much work for no benefit (as alliance is not an option).

OTOH, since the forces being worshipped are universal (fertility, planets, sky, wind, earth &c), "gluing" the pantheons (e.g., "Isis" == "Aphrodite") is usually possible instead.

Cf [Did Greeks and Romans tolerate those who only worshipped some of their gods?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/38165/1979)

Comment: "Every settlement had its own local deity, and neighbors had to trade, so they had to avoid religious wars, so they had to reconcile their local deities."

I don't think this is correct. I've never heard of religious wars or threats of religious wars between polytheistic peoples before the appearance of organized religion as we know it today. The idea of 'religion' is a rather new one. Could you share where you based this statement off of? I'd love to look further into this.

Comment: whilst some elements of some pantheons certainly can be explained as local genii loci, this explanation fails in many cases, as e.g. Egyptian religion had subpantheons (e.g. the ennead and ogdoad) that were still both localised and polytheistic, and many deities are defined largely by their relationships to each other (e.g. Asherah as the wife of El in Ugaritic and Canaanite polytheism)

Answer (score 6):

Well, in India, this argument is used to show that polytheistic religions are 'better' than 'Abrahamic' religions. It is one of the main right wing planks targeted at my people; so let me present a slightly contrarian view compared to the other answers

Religious iconoclasm was very much a part of pre-Christian cultures eg. Roman destruction of the Jewish Temple, the destruction surrounding the 2nd Punic war etc. At some point, it is not particularly possible to separate religion and secular culture into distinct baskets. Take for example, one of the principal arguments that the Chinese government uses for the takeover/retaking/conquest/occupation of Tibet, that the Dalai Lama was running a theocratic serfdom which had to be ended. The Tibetans may see it as integral to their religious identity, but the Chinese don't see it that way. Do events of that kind get classified under religious iconoclasm or secular political disputes?

In South Asia, Hindu-Buddhist relations are in many respects, as antagonistic as Hindu-Muslim relations, and in fact much more antagonistic than Buddhist-Christian relations. Anyone with a passing understanding of Myanmar and Sri-Lanka can easily see this. In Sri-Lanka, the Sinhalese national narrative is fundamentally built on the historical defense of Buddhist society against Tamil Hindu kings and is replete with tales of destroyed Buddhist temples and the trauma around it. Even in India, there has been genocidal levels of violence between Jains, Buddhists and Hindus.

I would also claim that Christian exclusivism is vastly over-hyped. I would definitely agree that such ideas are more a part of Christianity, than say, Japanese Shinto or Chinese Taoism. But the Christian social and political code is still predominantly Greco-Roman and not Jewish. I mean, why does say Nepal trust the UK more than their co-religionists in India. Are they incapable of realizing that the exclusivism of Christianity would make any nation with a Christian culture fundamentally antagonistic towards pagan societies? Well, it seems that is not their historical experience. In a practical setting, Christian societies don't derive their social behavior from theological ideas of exclusivity.

Even in a theological sense, exclusivity was never a big part of Christian belief system. In a mainline protestant setting, I have never heard a single sermon about one god, or why monotheism is better than polytheism. In fact, the main reason Christ was killed was because he went against the strict exclusivity of the time. Evangelicals generally seem bigger than they are because America has such a global cultural presence, but in terms of numbers, they are not really that many.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I myself have compared monotheistic and polytheistic views as part of my sermons. E.g. the book of Job only makes sense in a monotheistic setting: there is no dilemma of a just God causing Job to suffer if you can easily ascribe it to another deity. Monotheism is so central to Christianity, God being described in superlatives like all-powerful, all-knowing, etc, - it just makes no sense to assume there might be another god on the same level. ...

Comment: Therefore, monotheism vs. polytheism works in a different way: There is only one almighty God. In comparison, all the other gods are merely statues, made of stone or wood. Because God is almighty, he does not need his followers to fight for him. Instead, he commands them to love the pagans. Then, they themselves might put away their old gods, and follow the one true God.

Comment: "[...] Christ was killed was because he went against the strict exclusivity of the time." No, the Jews had Jesus killed for blasphemy - He claimed that He *was* the god of the Jews, not some other god.

Comment: @Spitemaster Distinction without a difference.

Comment: The difference is in whether Jesus (implicitly or explicitly) supported henotheism/polytheism.  Your claim implies that He did, but there's no indication that that's the case.  It's possible to make the argument that Paul was a henotheist, rightly or wrongly, ("For even if there are so-called gods, whether in heaven or on earth (as indeed there are many 'gods' and many 'lords')" - 1 Cor 8:5) but I don't think you can make the same argument about Jesus.

Comment: It was clear to everyone around him, that he was treading theological 'no-go zone' with his son-of-God claims. This Bart Ehrmann argument not on strong ground. Whether he claimed to be God specifically is immaterial, but the cumulative meaning of his claims meant that he was elevating himself to something that clashed directly with 'monotheism'. And it was precisely for this 'theological' blasphemy that he was punished. It is a bit like with Russia and the special military operation.

Comment: @user24582 I don't think monotheism has ever been a significant part of Christian belief or practice. Right from the first century, Christianity was built around Christ, the Jewish God, Roman pagan borrowed ideas like the virgin, books, relics and an assortment of customs. The primary attachment of the masses to divinity of any kind was always loosely distributed towards all these details and was never centralized, even partially, towards any ideological totem like monotheism. That's not to say that strict monotheistic schools don't exist, but they were always insignificant.

Comment: @Spitemaster "He claimed that He was the god of the Jews..." Wrong! The promised Jewish Messiah was a human-only leader. Messiah = incarnate god is a Christian misrepresentation.

Comment: "In fact, the main reason Christ was killed was because he went against the strict exclusivity of the time." Wrong. The *historical* Jesus was convicted of *sedition*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Mathew 26: 65 Then the high priest tore his clothes and said, “He has spoken blasphemy! Why do we need any more witnesses? Look, now you have heard the blasphemy. In fact the blasphemy allegations were the clinching crimes for which he was killed, but obviously there was a general dislike towards the tone of his teachings as a whole.

Comment: @ever_free a) It might look like that from the outside, and even the Protestant half of Christianity would say that, in the Roman Catholic Church, things got way out of hands with Mary and the saints. But Mary and the saints have always been thought of as parts of creation, not gods. b) Regarding Christ, he is part of the Trinity, so there is still only one God. All of the major Christian denominations affirm this doctrine.

Comment: @user24582 Sure, they do have it as part of the Nicene creed, but in emphasis and practice, very little of Christianity follows from the singularity of God. In India the most famous churches are dedicated to Mary, and whatever be the doctrine, the practice of the faith is not particularly monotheistic. But it is not just Mary and the saints, look at the Russian church and their worship around relics and stuff. It is not something where the doctrine of monotheism is given much thought whatsoever.

Comment: @ever_free Yes, that was one of the major points of the Reformation. I'd say that humans tend to favor polytheism, so it crept in, at least in practice. But Judaism and Christianity are fundamentally monotheistic. The 10 commandments are part of every catechism I know of, taught to every new member, and they have 'no other gods' and 'no idols' right on top.

Answer (score -2):

Religions don't believe in anything. It is people that believe or do not.

The adherents of the Greek and Roman pantheons simply acknowledged the other pantheon by looking for correspondances: Jupiter was the Roman interpretation of Zeus whilst Juno, the wife of Jupiter was the Roman interpretation of Hera, the wife of Zeus.

Given these correspondances would have only made the belief of the believers even stronger as another people would seem to believe in the same pantheon.